# How do I split a String into different Strings without a divider

Tags: java, string, split

I have a string containing 1 word and I have to split this word into separate characters. I saw some posts about splitting strings but I only found some that split between like `- or \\n`.

**For example**

I have the Static string that's `"fantastic"`
how do I split this into all separate character strings? I do not know what is in the String each time I just have to separate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-separate-the-individual-characters-from-a-string/?

Comment: `String[] parts = "fantastic".split("");` ?

Comment: What did you try? Maybe you can a look at the documentation.  https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html

Comment: `char[] str = "fantastic".toCharArray();`

Comment: then char[1] would be the first one created right.  so in the word fantastic it would be char[1] = "f" . I do not work with Strings alot so I am not quite sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate like this:

```java
String s = "ABCDE";
s.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.println((char) c));
```

Or you could collect them in a List by using this instead (Requires Java version 16):

```java
List<String> list = s.chars().mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c)).toList();
```

or if you prefer an array:

**EDIT**: simplified

```java
String[] array = s.split("");
```

Comment: With the arraylist how do I then specifically get an entry that has been put into the arraylist right here for example I want to get the third word printed that has been seperated here into the arraylist array.

Comment: I got the  List<String> list = word.chars().mapToObj(c -> String.valueOf((char) c)).toList(); However it gives the error that tolist() is an undeclared method now. and I also changed the list to another variable as I already use the list var for another list.

Comment: I am using bluej 5.0.2  as it is for a project for school and its required for us to use it. any way to do it with the java bluej uses I think its like java 11+ orso that they use I am not quite sure

Comment: If I use the String version the Arraylist will be named string right or am I wrong here? so I have to call it up using array.get(6);

Comment: with an array you get elements with `arrayname[index]` (index starts with 0)

Comment: I updated the array part with a much simpler version.